# Cartesian product type error

Tags: list, recursion, types, ocaml, cartesian-product

I'm trying to make a function that given 2 lists (`'a list` and `'b list`) returns a `('a*'b) list` which it is the Cartesian product of both lists.
I tried this, but it gets a `'a list list` instead `'a list`, equal for `'b`.
So, I'm asking if someone could tell me where I'm wrong and why OCaml asks for `'a list list` instead `'a list`.

```
let lprod l1 l2 =
let rec aux lista la lb =
    match la,lb with 
        [],_ -> lista
        |ha::ta,[] -> aux lista ta l2
        |ha::ta,hb::tb -> aux (ha,hb) la tb
in aux ([],[]) l1 l2;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several problems here:

1. You're calling `aux` with an initial accumulator value of `([], [])`. That's a tuple of two lists, not a list of tuples.
2. In the last pattern matching branch you're calling `aux` recursively with `(ha, hb)`, which is a single tuple, not a list of tuples.

What you probably want is to have the initial value in 1 be just an empty list, and then append the tuple to the accumulator in 2 using cons (`::`).

Edit: Here's a fixed version of your implementation:

```
let lprod l1 l2 =
  let rec aux acc la lb =
    match la, lb with 
    | [], _ -> acc
    | ha::ta, [] -> aux acc ta l2
    | ha::ta, hb::tb -> aux ((ha, hb)::acc) la tb
  in aux [] l1 l2;;
```

Comment: Yes I want these accumulator, but how can I call for a list of tuples instead a tuple of list in the aux?

Comment: @JulioVillanueva See the updated answer for a working implementation

Comment: This works close to be perfect. It returns the reverse of what I want, so I used: | [], _ -> rev acc to get what I need, thanks